# Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, google-signin

I'm building a site that has a pretty standard RESTful web service to handle persistence and complex business logic. The UI I'm building to consume this service is using [Angular 2](https://angular.io/) with components written in TypeScript.

Rather than build my own authentication system, I'm hoping to rely on Google Sign-In for Websites. The idea being that users will come to the site, sign in via the framework provided there and then send along the resulting ID tokens, which the server hosting the RESTful service can then verify.

In the Google Sign-In documentation there are [instructions for creating the login button via JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#customizing_the_automatically_rendered_sign-in_button_recommended) which is what needs to happen since the login button is being rendered dynamically in an Angular template. The relevant portion of the template:

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
  <p>You need to log in.</p>
  <div id="{{googleLoginButtonId}}"></div>
</div>
<div class="main-application">
  <p>Hello, {{userDisplayName}}!</p>
</div>
```

And the Angular 2 component definition in Typescript:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

// Google's login API namespace
declare var gapi:any;

@Component({
    selector: "sous-app",
    templateUrl: "templates/sous-app-template.html"
})
export class SousAppComponent {
  googleLoginButtonId = "google-login-button";
  userAuthToken = null;
  userDisplayName = "empty";

  constructor() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  // Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
  // rendering of a view.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
    api.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,
      {
        "onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
      });
  }

  // Triggered after a user successfully logs in using the Google external
  // login provider.
  onGoogleLoginSuccess(loggedInUser) {
    this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

The basic flow goes:

1. Angular renders the template and the message "Hello, empty!" is shown.
2. The `ngAfterViewInit` hook is fired and the `gapi.signin2.render(...)` method is called which converts the empty div into a Google login button. This works correctly and clicking on that button will trigger the login process.
3. This also attaches the component's `onGoogleLoginSuccess` method to actually process the returned token after a user logs in.
4. Angular detects that the `userDisplayName` property has changed and updates the page to now display "Hello, Craig (or whatever your name is)!".

The first problem that occurs is in the `onGoogleLoginSuccess` method. Notice the `console.log(...)` calls in the `constructor` and in that method. As expected, the one in the `constructor` returns the Angular component. The one in the `onGoogleLoginSuccess` method, however, returns the JavaScript `window` object.

So it looks like the context is getting lost in the process of hopping out to Google's login logic so my next step was to try incorporating jQuery's `$.proxy` call to hang on to the correct context. So I import the jQuery namespace by adding `declare var $:any;` to the top of the component and then convert the contents of the `ngAfterViewInit` method to be:

```
// Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
// rendering of a view.
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var loginProxy = $.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);

    // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
    gapi.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,
      {
        "onSuccess": loginProxy,
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
      });
}
```

After adding that, the two `console.log` calls return the same object so property values are now updating correctly. The second log message shows the object with the expected updated property values.

Unfortunately, the Angular template does not get updated when this happens. While debugging, I stumbled on something that I believe explains what is going on. I added the following line to the end of the `ngAfterViewInit` hook:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.googleLoginButtonId = this.googleLoginButtonId },
  5000);
```

This shouldn't really do anything. It just waits five seconds after the hook ends and then sets a property value equal to itself. However, with the line in place the `"Hello, empty!"` message turns into `"Hello, Craig!"` about five seconds after the page has loaded. This suggest to me that Angular just isn't noticing that the property values are changing in the `onGoogleLoginSuccess` method. So when something else happens to notify Angular that property values have changed (such as the otherwise useless self-assignment above), Angular wakes up and updates everything.

Obviously that's not a hack I want to leave in place so I'm wondering if any Angular experts out there can clue me in? Is there some call I should be making to force Angular to notice some properties have changed?

**UPDATED 2016-02-21 to provided clarity on the specific answer that solved the problem**

I ended up needing to use both pieces of the suggestion provided in the selected answer.

First, exactly as suggested, I needed to convert the `onGoogleLoginSuccess` method to use an arrow function. Secondly, I needed to make use of an `NgZone` object to make sure that the property updates occurred in a context of which Angular is aware. So the final method ended up looking like

```
onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {
    this._zone.run(() => {
        this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    });
}
```

I did need to import the `_zone` object: `import {Component, NgZone} from "angular2/core";`

I also needed to inject it as suggested in the answer via the class's contructor: `constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }`

Comment: New to typescript, where does the `gapi` come from? I'm using your example to implement google login as well. I declare the var `gapi` - but it's an empty var right? so when trying to call the method off of i I get a load of errors. Where does `gapi` come from? What bit am I missing?

Comment: The gapi variable is actually an object defined in the Google API's JavaScript file (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton.) You'll need to include that script on the page where your script is running.

The declare statement is just making it visible to the rest of the TypeScript code, not creating it.

If the variable is just an empty object for you, my guess is that script needs to be included.

Comment: Thanks it works now, I also needed the google-signin-client-id header with my client id.

Comment: But there i am facing below issue.   Once i clicked allow in google auth page, it goes to a link **"https://accounts.google.com/o/noscript"**. This page says that **You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.

Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.**   But i have javascript enabled in my browser. My question is why it is not rendering back to the origin URL?

Comment: It is working for first time. but whenever i attempt to login again after logout i get the following error.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"    .  

Due to this callback function 'onGoogleLoginSuccess' is not calling

Comment: I have two comonent A and B. The login button is in A. i  come to A and with out login i return to B then i come again to component A and trying to Login. in this case 'onGoogleLoginSuccess' function is not working and the following error comes -

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at G_ (cb=gapi.loaded_0:271)
    at H_.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:274)
    at Function.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:151)
    at MessagePort.c.port1.onmessage (cb=gapi.loaded_0:73)

I need your help @CraigPhillips

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For your first problem solution is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will preserve context of `this` :

```
  onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {
    this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    console.log(this);
  }
```

Second issue is happening because third-party scripts run outside the context of Angular. Angular uses `zones` so when you run something, for example `setTimeout()`, which is monkey-patched to run in the zone, Angular will get notified. You would run jQuery in zone like this:

```
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      $.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);
    });
  }
```

There are many questions/answers about the zone with much better explanations then mine, if you want to know more, but it shouldn't be an issue for your example if you use arrow function.

Comment: I am using this same code. but i am getting empty as `userDisplayName ` even after I logged in

Comment: Where to provide client_id here? I am getting error like **client_id missing**.

Comment: @Jyotirmay you add it in <head> tag of index. html. Like that <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">

Comment: @InsaneRose.. Yeah thanks. I saw that and added. Login with Google button renders now, But when clicked "Allow" on google auth page it renders me to **https://accounts.google.com/o/noscript** which says **You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.

Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.** But Javascript is enabled in my browser. Why is it not going back to origin URL?

Comment: add 'http://localhost/callback/' to "Authorized redirect URIs" in console.developers.google.com.

Comment: I have two comonent A and B. The login button is in A. i  come to A and with out login i return to B then i come again to component A and trying to Login. in this case 'onGoogleLoginSuccess' function is not working and the following error comes -

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at G_ (cb=gapi.loaded_0:271)
    at H_.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:274)
    at Function.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:151)
    at MessagePort.c.port1.onmessage (cb=gapi.loaded_0:73)

Answer (score 8):

I made a google-login component if you want an example.

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.initAPI = new Promise(
        (resolve) => {
          window['onLoadGoogleAPI'] =
              () => {
                  resolve(window.gapi);
          };
          this.init();
        }
    )
  }

  init(){
    let meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.name = 'google-signin-client_id';
    meta.content = 'xxxxx-xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadGoogleAPI';
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(node);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initAPI.then(
      (gapi) => {
        gapi.load('auth2', () =>
        {
          var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'xxxxx-xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: 'profile email'
          });
          auth2.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById('googleSignInButton'), {},
              this.onSuccess,
              this.onFailure
          );
        });
      }
    )
  }

  onSuccess = (user) => {
      this._ngZone.run(
          () => {
              if(user.getAuthResponse().scope ) {
                  //Store the token in the db
                  this.socialService.googleLogIn(user.getAuthResponse().id_token)
              } else {
                this.loadingService.displayLoadingSpinner(false);
              }
          }
      );
  };

  onFailure = (error) => {
    this.loadingService.displayLoadingSpinner(false);
    this.messageService.setDisplayAlert("error", error);
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
        //display spinner
        this.loadingService.displayLoadingSpinner(false);
    });
  }
```

It's a bit late but I just want to give an example if someone want to use google login api with ng2.

Answer (score 3):

Include the below file in your index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

login.html

```
<button id="glogin">google login</button>
```

login.ts

```
declare const gapi: any;
public auth2:any
ngAfterViewInit() {
     gapi.load('auth2',  () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '788548936361-h264uq1v36c5ddj0hf5fpmh7obks94vh.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('glogin'));
    });
}

public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (loggedInUser) => {  
      console.log( loggedInUser);

      }, function (error) {
        // alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });

 }
```

Comment: `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` is being blocked by my browser, it's really weird. I get this message in console "Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js”."

Answer (score 1):

Try this package -
`npm install angular2-google-login`

Github - https://github.com/rudrakshpathak/angular2-google-login

I've implemented Google login in Angular2. Just import the package and you are ready to go.

**Steps -**

`import { AuthService, AppGlobals } from 'angular2-google-login';`

*Supply providers -*
`providers: [AuthService];`

*Constructor -*
`constructor(private _googleAuth: AuthService){}`

*Set Google client ID -* 
`AppGlobals.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'SECRET_CLIENT_ID';`

*Use this to call the service -*

```
this._googleAuth.authenticateUser(()=>{
  //YOUR_CODE_HERE 
});
```

*To logout -*

```
this._googleAuth.userLogout(()=>{
  //YOUR_CODE_HERE 
});
```

Comment: I am getting  "gapi is not defined" error. Tried to fix by reviewing https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-login but could not. How to use AfterViewInit for this component? Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer by Sasxa also helped me but I found that I can bind this to the onSuccess function using **.bind(this)**, that way I don't have to create the function with a fat arrow.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  var loginProxy = $.proxy(this.onGoogleLoginSuccess, this);

  // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
  gapi.signin2.render(
    this.googleLoginButtonId,
    {
      "onSuccess": loginProxy.bind(this),
      "scope": "profile",
      "theme": "dark"
    });
}
```