# Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript doesn't work after sign out

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular

After following the steps in this thread:

[Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530483/google-sign-in-for-websites-and-angular-2-using-typescript)

I could successfully log in with Google after y navigate other component with router.navigate(). I used the logout button like this:

```
signOut() {var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
           auth2.signOut().then(x=> {}).then(this._router.parent.navigate('Login'] ));
```

This last command sent me again to the login component, the difference is, that if i tried to log in again nothing happens (the on success function is not being called), although inside the google developer console it shows that the token is being retrieved.

```
access_token: "ya29.pgKa3wixEFbsLB-yUW2Mf3s8YvasRoM5javqTc9TxQgnW-  WUdxGD0CYyZj7p107e9w"
expires_in: 3600
```

Hope you can help me.

PD: the code that is making the login process right now:

```
gapi.signin2.render(
   this.googleLoginButtonId,
   {
     "onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,
     "scope": "profile",
     "theme": "dark",
     "width": 240,
     "height": 50,
     "longtitle": true,
     'onfailure': this.onGoogleFailure
   });
```

Thanks in advance.