# google sign-in with angular2 and typescript - where to get gapi?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to use google sign-in with angular2 by following this question: [Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530483/google-sign-in-for-websites-and-angular-2-using-typescript#)

But I'm getting an error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
    at LoginAppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:3000/app/login.component.js:33:9)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.template.js:46:68)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12143:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12247:48)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12169:23)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChangesInternal (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12154:18)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12143:18)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12247:48)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:10397:69)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9911:88)
```

Evidently gapi isn't defined - which I can understand as I seem to only be declaring an empty var.

My current code is as below:

```
import {Component, NgZone} from "@angular/core";

declare var gapi: any;

@Component({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl: "templates/login-template.html"
})
export class LoginAppComponent {
  googleLoginButtonId = "google-login-button";
  userAuthToken = null;
  userDisplayName = "empty";

  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {
    console.log(this);
  }

  // Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
  // rendering of a view.
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Converts the Google login button stub to an actual button.
    gapi.signin2.render(
      this.googleLoginButtonId,
      {
        "onSuccess": this.onGoogleLoginSuccess,
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark"
      });
  }

  // Triggered after a user successfully logs in using the Google external
  // login provider.
  onGoogleLoginSuccess = (loggedInUser) => {
    this._zone.run(() => {
        this.userAuthToken = loggedInUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        this.userDisplayName = loggedInUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    });
}
}
```

The template loads fine, it is just the `gapi` bit.

So my question is: what am I missing? How do I need to be defining `gapi` for it to work?

Here is my main app.component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginAppComponent } from './login.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
            <script>
            window.onLoadCallback = function(){
              gapi.auth2.init({
                  client_id: 'filler_text_for_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                });
            }
            </script>
             <h1>Angular2 P.O.C.</h1>
             <login></login>`,
  directives: [LoginAppComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you included the Google platform API script?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144874/gapi-is-not-defined-google-sign-in-issue-with-gapi-auth2-init) for instructions on how to wait for the GAPI script to load before executing your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Can you be a bit more detailed? JS/TS with angular is definitely a weak spot for me. I went through the question and added it to my main app template - not the prettiest solution. It still isn't working though and I'm not entirely sure if what I did was right - or how to correct it.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399419/angular-js-and-google-api-client-js-gapi) provides a couple of strategies for using the Google API with Angular. It sounds like you're encountering a condition where Angular tries to access the `gapi` object before the `platform.js` script is loaded. Instead of adding the `<script>` tag to your app template, can you load `platform.js` along with the Angular core, e.g. in the html where you declare `ng-app`?

Comment: It works now thanks! I was also missing the google-signin-client-id meta header.

Comment: @Scironic I tried it but it didn't work. Can you help me by sending code? <3

Answer (score 6):

I also had same problem in **Angular v4.0**. Removing  **async defer** from the **Google platform API script** solved my problem

My Problem was like below when I used Google platform api like :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

[image]

I solved my problem by discarding ***async defer*** from **Google platform api script**  as like below in my ***index.html***  :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: Removing _async defer_ in NG 4 solved my problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much Amir :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following file to your project structure for removing the error.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gapi.auth2/index.d.ts

This will make gapi available in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by calling the following script in index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
```

**Note:**

Use the following script without **async defer**:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform."></script>
```

and use **async defer** in this script

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
```