# How to use angular2 with google oAuth

Tags: angular

Is there a npm package which works with google authentication. I tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2 (with angular2 2.1.0) but angular2-oauth2 has no option/method to take oAuth secret key. It opens google account, ask me to authorize and then redirects back but oAuthService.getIdentityClaims() is always "null"

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664350/google-sign-in-with-angular2-and-typescript-where-to-get-gapi?rq=1. I think it's good for you.

Comment: try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-oauth2