# OAuth 2.0 with Angular2

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I am onto a project wherein "sign in with Google" is made used. I went through many guides, tutorials and articles but none of them helped.
I am using Angular2 in the front end and is able to get the result following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) when in the index.html page. But when I export the functions and template to the other components nothing is shown up even though no errors. Attaching the index.html, app.component.ts along with.
Please help me out as I am new to Angular2 and a beginner in development.
Thank you in advance :)

```js
//app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>  <!--included this for try-->
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  onSignIn(googleUser) {
  // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
  let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
  console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
  console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
  console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

  // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
  let id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
};
}
```

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
//main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The code inside the app.component.ts works fine when put in index.html

Comment: can you also include the code of app.module.ts , the file where you have @NgModule and also main.ts where you bootstrap your app.

Comment: It's not possible to use `<srcipt>` tags in Angular template so you need to build a custom login: see this question for how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530483/google-sign-in-for-websites-and-angular-2-using-typescript#