# Sign Up using Facebook - Angular 4 Typescript

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular, typescript

Let me first start by saying I've searched for an answer to this question for quite some time...

This is the first time I am working wit Social Networks. I would like to know if there is Facebook and twitter sign in using Typescript

Looks like there is Google Sign in using Typescript.

[Google Sign-In for Websites and Angular 2 using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530483/google-sign-in-for-websites-and-angular-2-using-typescript)

I registered in facebook developer and add product(which is localhost) and followed the instructions. Is there any plugin or other way to use Facebook and twitter using Typescript

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve is to use Firebase more specifically angularfire 2 please check it example for an easy way to add social authentication to your application.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is authentication, something that is done on the back-end. If you are using Node/Express (javascript server side) you'd want to look into PassportJS, and if you're considering adding in access-control, consider connect-roles.

You will use Angular to provide a registration and login form to make GET/POST requests to the server, as well as a user service to handle login/logout and isLoggedIn methods. Using HTTP response codes, you'll know how to route the user (login success or failure.) Additionally, AuthGuards are another concept of front-end authentication.